# Refresh animation in actionbar customview imagebutton

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I created an application from a demo.  The application is enabled with actionbar.  It contain customview in top and actionview items in bottom.  In the top custom view an imagebutton is located.  I want rounding circle animation (refresh animation) when the imagebutton is clicked.  Is any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got a solution

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

animation starting

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,360,
  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotate.setDuration(1000);
rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
imageButton.startAnimation(rotate);
```

animation stopping

```
imageButton.clearAnimation();
```